# Wix Burn: Setting Engine LocalSource() to extract Burn contents

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I only guess that the following would set sLocalSourcePath where Payloads would be deployed and would be executed further by [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) instead of doing that in some Temp folder.

> Engine.SetLocalSource(sPackageId, sPayloadId, sLocalSourcePath)

If yes, then under which event, should it be called?

Answer (score 1):

`SetLocalSource` lets the Bootstrapper Application tell the engine where it can find the source of a specific payload or package.

It is not possible for a BA to modify the location of the package cache.  There is a [feature request](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4278/) open that would allow the user to relocate it (which would apply to all bundles).